# android cannot be resolved or is not a field error

Tags: java, android

I created a tictactoe android game, and when i try to link the strings.xml file to activity.java I receive an error.

Here is my activity.java

```
package com.tictactoeoyna.www;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TicTacToeOynaActivity extends Activity {

    private TicTacToeOyun mGame;

    private Button mBoardButtons[];

    private TextView mInfoTextView;
    private TextView mHumanCount;
    private TextView mTieCount;
    private TextView mAndroidCount;

    private int mHumanCounter = 0;
    private int mTieCounter = 0;
    private int mAndroidCounter = 0;

    private boolean mHumanFirst = true;
    private boolean mGameOver = false;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mBoardButtons = new Button[TicTacToeOyun.getBOARD_SIZE()];
        mBoardButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);// it should be blue but not
        mBoardButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);//same 
        mBoardButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        mBoardButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        mBoardButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        mBoardButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        mBoardButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        mBoardButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        mBoardButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);//until here

        mInfoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information);
        mHumanCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humanCount);
        mTieCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tiesCount);
        mAndroidCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.androidCount);

        mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
        mAndroidCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));

        mGame = new TicTacToeOyun();

        startNewGame();

    }

    private void startNewGame()
    {
        mGame.clearBoard();

        for (int i = 0; i < mBoardButtons.length; i++)
        {
            mBoardButtons[i].setText("");
            mBoardButtons[i].setEnabled(true);
            mBoardButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(i));
        }

        if (mHumanFirst)
        {
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.first_human);
            mHumanFirst = false;
        }
        else
        {
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
            int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
            setMove(mGame.ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
            mHumanFirst = true;
        }
    }

    private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        int location;

        public ButtonClickListener(int location)
        {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if (!mGameOver)
            {
                if (mBoardButtons[location].isEnabled())
                {
                    setMove(mGame.HUMAN_PLAYER, location);

                    int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                    if (winner == 0)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
                        int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
                        setMove(mGame.ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
                        winner = mGame.checkForWinner();                        
                    }

                    if (winner == 0)
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_human);
                    else if (winner == 1)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                        mTieCounter++;
                        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }
                    else if (winner == 2)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_human_wins);
                        mHumanCounter++;
                        mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_android_wins);
                        mAndroidCounter++;
                        mAndroidCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setMove(char player, int location)
    {
        mGame.setMove(player, location);
        mBoardButtons[location].setEnabled(false);
        mBoardButtons[location].setText(String.valueOf(player));
        if (player == mGame.HUMAN_PLAYER)
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        else
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

The error is on one, two, three...nine and information count, human count etc.  Here is my fragment file, so why can't I see one, two, three....nine labeled blue?  Why is it not recognized? What have I done wrong ? I received the errors after findviewbyid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/playArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="one"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/one"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/two"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/three"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/three"
                android:textSize="70dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/four"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/four"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/five"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/five"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/six"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/six"
                android:textSize="70dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/seven"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/seven"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eight"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/eight"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nine"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/nine"
                android:textSize="70dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/information"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/info"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/human"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/human" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/humanCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ties"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ties" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tiesCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/android" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/androidCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove import android.R; from your imports.

Comment: Remove import android.R;

Comment: that does not work. if i remove i get the r cannot be resolved to variable error and it suggest me to add it.

Comment: try this `import com.tictactoeoyna.www.R;`

Comment: not working to import that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.tictactoeoyna.www.R;
```

and remove`import android.R;`

Comment: The import com.tictactoeoyna.www.R cannot be resolved this error occurs when i add

Comment: remove import android.R; and then clean the project

Comment: iam getting the same r cannot be resolved error after i clean the project and remove import android.r.

Comment: string format should be like `<string name="one">1</string>` and for Button one button_id is wrong. It should be `android:id="@+id/one"`

Comment: they are just like your example so no problem on my string format too.i edit the button id nothing change still getting that annoying error.

Comment: r cannot be resolved error. and suggest me to add android.r when i do that i get the  "one"cannot be resolved or is not a field error replace one with other findviewbyid things.

Comment: You may have any error in your xml files like layout, string and AndroidManifest. Check it

Comment: Is your application have R.java file in gen folder?

Answer (score 0):

When you got this type of error at anywhere and you have `import android.R;` then just remove `import android.R;`.

Comment: not worked for me. i need those findviewbyid need to be blue its not recognized.

Comment: if this not worked then check your xml files for errors

Comment: it seems that my xml files are ok.

Comment: you should clean and build the project and if problem remains then restart your ide